# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_product()

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging, woocommerce

After importing my production WordPress-associated website to my local Xampp environment, I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_product()
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\siliconharvest\wp-content\themes\storefront-child\functions.php:62
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\siliconharvest\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(286):
>   wc_variable_simple_conditions('') #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\siliconharvest\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(310):
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\siliconharvest\wp-includes\plugin.php(453):
>   WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\siliconharvest\wp-includes\general-template.php(2614):
>   do_action('wp_head') #4
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\siliconharvest\wp-content\themes\storefront\header.php(18):
>   wp_head() #5
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\siliconharvest\wp-includes\template.php(688):
>   require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #6
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\siliconharvest\wp-includes\template.php(647):
>   load_template('C:\xampp\htdocs...', true) #7
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\siliconharvest\wp-includes\general-template.php(
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\siliconharvest\wp-content\themes\storefront-child\functions.php
>   on line 62

I have attempted the following diagnostic steps, with no effect on the error:

1. Disabled all plugins, including the plugin which concerns itself with products (Woocommerce)
2. Re-named the storefront-child\functions.php file (to temporarily disable it)
3. Changed the template to something other than store-front child

Yet the error persists regardless of any of the above steps.  The correct solution must make all these errors go away.

Edit: lines 1-73 of the functions.php file referenced in the error:

```
<?php
// BEGIN Remove "Storefront Designed by WooThemes" from Footer as per https://danielsantoro.com/remove-storefront-designed-woothemes/
add_action('init', 'custom_remove_footer_credit', 10);
function custom_remove_footer_credit()
{
    remove_action('storefront_footer', 'storefront_credit', 20);
    add_action('storefront_footer', 'custom_storefront_credit', 20);
}

function custom_storefront_credit()
{
?>
    <div class="site-info">
<div class="deferred-menu-items">
<ul style="list-style-type: none;" class="footer-menu">
<li style="display:inline-block" class="menu-item-156"><a href="/about/">About Us</a></li><!--
--><li style="display:inline-block" class="menu-item-189"><a href="/faq/">FAQ</a></li><!--
--><li style="display:inline-block" class="fa-delivery"><a href="/delivery/">Delivery</a></li><!--
--><li style="display:inline-block" class="fa-returns"><a href="/returns/">Returns</a></li><!--
--><li style="display:inline-block" class="menu-item-464"><a href="/store-policies/"><i class="far fa-handshake"></i> Store Policies</a></li><!--
--><!--<li style="display:inline-block" class="menu-item-1024"><a href="/articles/">Articles</a></li>--><!--
--><li style="display:inline-block" class="affiliates"><a href="/about-the-silicon-harvest-affiliates-program/"><i class="fas fa-bullhorn"></i> Affiliates Programme</a></li>
<!--<li style="display:inline-block" class="fa-opas"><a href="/overseas-parts-acquisition-service-opas/">Overseas Parts Acquisition Service (OPAS)</a></li>-->
</ul>
</div>
        &copy; <?php
    echo get_bloginfo('name') . ' ' . get_the_date('Y') . ' | ABN: 31 022 705 565 | <a style="color:blue" href="/terms-of-service-and-privacy-policy/">Terms of Service/Privacy Policy</a> <div class="front-page-contact">
<a style="color:blue" href="/contact-us/#aggs-contact-form">Contact Form</a> | mob: 0424 214 930 | tel: (02) 8007 6871 <!--| mob: +61 424 214 930 (international) / tel: +612 8007 6871 -->| <a style="color:blue" href="mailto:mail@siliconharvest.com.au">mail@siliconharvest.com.au</a><br />Live contact hours from 9am-9pm (AEST/AEDT or Sydney/Melbourne/ACT/TAS time), Mon-Sun</div>';
?>
    </div><!-- .site-info -->
    <?php
}
// END Remove "Storefront Designed by WooThemes" from Footer

/* START add microdata relating to item condition to satisfy Google Merchant's optional advice - as per https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/15797#issuecomment-355744594 */
add_filter('woocommerce_structured_data_product_offer', 'filter_woocommerce_structured_data_product', 10, 2);

/**
 * Add properties to the http://schema.org/Offer markup for all products.
 */
function filter_woocommerce_structured_data_product($markup, $product)
{
    /* By default, we assume all products sold in the ecommerce are in new condition */
    if (empty($markup['itemCondition'])) {
        $markup['itemCondition'] = 'http://schema.org/NewCondition';
    }
    return $markup;
}
/* END add microdata */


// as per https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/276941/woocommerce-add-extra-field-to-variation-product/277556 
// based on http://www.remicorson.com/woocommerce-custom-fields-for-variations/ 

//THESE ACTIONS AND FILTER HANDLE YOUR PRODUCT VARIATION FIELDS + add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'load_variation_settings_fields' ); which you have inserted into a conditional
add_action('woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'variation_settings_fields', 10, 3);
add_action('woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_variation_settings_fields', 10, 2);

add_action('wp_head', 'wc_variable_simple_conditions');
function wc_variable_simple_conditions()
{
    if (is_product()) {
        global $post;
        $post_id = $post->ID;
        $product = wc_get_product($post_id);
        $type    = $product->get_type();
        if ($type == 'variable') {
            add_filter('woocommerce_available_variation', 'load_variation_settings_fields');
        } elseif ($type == 'simple') {
            add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_data_above_add_to_cart_button', 41);
        }
    }
}
```

The line `if (is_product()) {` is line 62.

Comment: It's says the error comes from file "functions.php:line 62", so you should share the codes from that file as well

Comment: @MdKowsarHossain  I have now included in OP

Answer (score 5):

First check if woocommerce activated then call function:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'wc_variable_simple_conditions');
function wc_variable_simple_conditions(){
    if (!class_exists('WooCommerce')) return; // add this line
    if (is_product()) {
        global $post;
        $post_id = $post->ID;
        $product = wc_get_product($post_id);
        $type    = $product->get_type();
        if ($type == 'variable') {
            add_filter('woocommerce_available_variation', 'load_variation_settings_fields');
        } elseif ($type == 'simple') {
            add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_data_above_add_to_cart_button', 41);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you `include` source of this function `includes/wc-conditional-functions.php`

http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/is_product/

Comment: I can confirm the file `wc-conditional-functions.php` can be found in `C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\siliconharvest\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes`.  Please advise.

Comment: is your Woocommerce plugin active ? check in DB with SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';

Comment: I found this term in the value for the active_plugins record `i:54;s:27:"woocommerce/woocommerce.php";`.  Does that tell you if Woocommerce is active?

Comment: I use Storefront, with a child theme for customisations.  The thing is, my live production website on my hosted server works fine.  Seems migrating an identical copy of the website to a local desktop environment broke Woocommerce...

Comment: may be it missed some files. try to copy your theme files again

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your function with this:

```
function wc_variable_simple_conditions()
{
    if ( !function_exists( 'is_product' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    if (is_product()) {
        global $post;
        $post_id = $post->ID;
        $product = wc_get_product($post_id);
        $type    = $product->get_type();
        if ($type == 'variable') {
            add_filter('woocommerce_available_variation', 'load_variation_settings_fields');
        } elseif ($type == 'simple') {
            add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_data_above_add_to_cart_button', 41);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the error persists...  Feel free to try again  :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'wc_variable_simple_conditions');
function wc_variable_simple_conditions() {
    if (is_singular( array( 'product' ) )) {
        global $post;
        $post_id = $post->ID;
        $product = wc_get_product($post_id);
        $type = $product->get_type();
        if ($type == 'variable') {
            add_filter('woocommerce_available_variation', 'load_variation_settings_fields');
        } elseif ($type == 'simple') {
            add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_data_above_add_to_cart_button', 41);
        }
    }
}
```

If you get errors maybe the custom post type 'product' doesn't exist.

Comment: Your code returned: `Warning: require(../../..//wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\siliconharvest\wp-content\themes\storefront-child\functions.php on line 3`

`Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '../../..//wp-load.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\siliconharvest\wp-content\themes\storefront-child\functions.php on line 3`  What does this mean?  What is the fix?

Comment: What function() are you calling in line 3 on functions.php? Could yoy pastebin it?

Comment: You can use `is_product()` instead of `is_singular( array( 'product' ) )` for efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following things if it works?

- Try to update theme if new update exist for theme.
- If woo commerce folder exists inside active theme folder then rename
  that woocommerce folder and check it.